# Calling a method with instance creation

Tags: c#

```
public class Deposit
{
    private static readonly Deposit instance = new Deposit();
    public static Deposit Instance
    {
        get
        { return instance; }
    }

    public void Update_Approval()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Update");
    }

    private void Main()
    {
        Deposit.Instance.Update_Approval();
        Update_Approval();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

I have downloaded this source code from the internet.

I am just wondering the way of calling the `Update_Approval` method from the `Main` method, I saw they used `Deposit.Instance.Update_Approval()` to call but
if I just directly call `Update_Approval()` that can provide the same result.

So, what is the purpose of using this way to call the method?

Answer (score 2):

What you see is a singleton pattern implementation. The singleton pattern is used to only create one single instance of an object across the entire program execution. Often factory classes are created with this pattern to prevent recreation of an object.

You indeed can create an instance and call this method in this case, that is why usually singleton classes have a private constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can in fact call `Update_Approval()` directly from `Main()`. Your `Main()` needs to be a static method. And from this method it can only act on instances of `Deposit` or other static methods. Apart from that as Patrick explains it is a [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), and can be used to control that only one instance of that class is ever available.